# A review item (audit) I cannot sensibly action

Tags: discussion

I have just been been presented with:

https://superuser.com/review/late-answers/540432.

My choices are:

- <kbd>flag</kbd>

  I can't flag it again (I already flagged it VLQ and it was deleted - that's how I knew it was an audit).
- <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd>

  This will fail the audit (I don't want to fail, obviously).
- <kbd>Skip</kbd>

  I suppose I have to skip, but this seems to defeat the purpose of the audit.

Am I missing something?

Comment: the purpose of the audit is to see you're paying attention. Clearly you are. Skip it

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I did, of course.

Comment: Did you just assume you couldn't flag it or did you try and failed?  My recollection is that you can flag it in the audit even if you flagged it before because it doesn't actually flag anything, it just checks whether you attempted to do the right response.  However, there is another option in the Late Answer review queue -- leave a comment.  That will pass the audit, rather than skipping it and being re-tested a few posts later.

Comment: @fixer1234 I tried to flag it and failed with a "You already flagged" message. I didn't take a screenshot :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you desperately want to pass the audit (i.e. not use the Skip button), you can press the downvote arrow. That will immediately cause you to pass this. Alternatively, writing a comment and pressing the Add Comment button also results in a pass for a known-bad audit.